# Recycler View Onclick android not working

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I've a `CustomersAdapter` class for my `RecyclerView`  and I m trying to implement onclick event on the RecyclerView row. But unfortunately its not working for me.

```
public class CustomersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomersAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    private List<Customers> customerList;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customers_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Customers customer = customerList.get(position);
        holder.customerName.setText(customer.getCustomerName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return customerList.size();

    }

    public CustomersAdapter(List<Customers> customerList,Context ctx) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView customerName;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            customerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition(); // gets item position
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Customers  customer= customerList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, customer.getCustomerName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML: customers_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/cust_img"
                android:src="@drawable/person"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cust_name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="HELLO"

                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cust_img"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cust_img" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any error or status ?

Comment: no application is runnig fine i tried to debug the app but its not entering into the onclick method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. Implement `onClick()` inside the constructor.

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    customerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition(); // gets item position
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                Customers  customer= customerList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, customer.getCustomerName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but dont know why its not working via interface goona select your anser after few minutes

Comment: If you are using the interface, you got to set the onClickListener() inside the constructor to the view varaible.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to set setOnClickListener.. add setOnClickListener in onCreateViewHolder

```
private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();
 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.customers_layout, parent, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

}
```

Comment: MyViewHolder is implementing onClickListener interface

Comment: but CustomersAdapter no onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to `setOnTouchListener();` for you list item layout. you can set touch listener for your main layout of you list item.

Answer (score 0):

set listener to holder.itemView.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Customers customer = customerList.get(position);
    holder.customerName.setText(customer.getCustomerName());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
```

in onBindViewHolder method.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add onClickListener to your view. Thats why your onclick in not working.
Here you need to add your click listener with your views.

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        customerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);

        //bind the click listener with your view, like
        customerName.setOnClickListerner(this); // now it will get called when you click this customerName view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewHolder` is not a `View` that implements `onClick()`. In that case, you could emulate it like so:

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    customerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cust_name);
    //you forgot to call this
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```